# How to create formula to sum with dynamic ranges? I just can't make the right syntax

Tags: vba, excel

So what I would like to do is add a sum formula to a cell, so it can be edited later(normally, not through vba). It sums up some cells, but the amount of cells is not always the same. Sometimes it's 4 cells, sometimes it's 10. So I'm trying to have:

```
lastrow = Sheets(7).Cells(Sheets(7).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

then using it:

```
Sheets(7).Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(b2:b&"lastrow")"
```

My problem is the syntax actually, I can't seem to make it right. How to add lastrow to this formula?

Hope it's understandable, English is not my native language.

Comment: Please add 4 spaces in front of your two lines of code, so it gets rendered as code. This will also show you what's wrong with your code, as you'll see `"=SUM(b2:b&"` in string color, `lastrow` in black, and `")"` in string color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing to concatenate.

`Sheets(7).Range("B" & lastrow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(b2:b" & lastrow & ")"`

Comment: Indeed, `"=SUM(b2:b&"lastrow")"` does not seem right

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .End(xlUp) method, I'd suggest that using Named Ranges and in particular the built-in structured referencing of Excel Tables/ListObjects would make for more robust and simpler code.

Using Named Ranges avoids hard-coding references in your code. If you hard code cell address into your code, those references will be pointing at the wrong place if you (or a user) later adds new rows/columns above/to the left of those hard-coded references. Using Names avoids this, and makes for more robust code.

I almost always use Excel Tables aka ListObjects to hold any data that VBA interacts with for the same reason...ListObjects are dynamic named ranges that Excel automatically expands/contracts to suit the data, and unlike .End(xlUp) they won't throw your code off if the column contains blanks.

So I'd do it like this:

```
Range("SomeNamedRange") = "=SUM(" & Range("SomeTable[SomeColumn]").Address & ")"
```

...or more likely, I'd use the [] shorthand notation:

```
[SomeNamedRange] = "=SUM(" & [SomeTable[SomeColumn]].Address & ")"
```